# How to prove this guess?

Tags: number-theory

Any positive integer can be multiplied by $2$ plus $1$ as many times as I need to reach a prime **(the number of operations cannot be $0$)**

Comment: what do you mean by "for several times?" If you mean "as many times as I need to reach a prime," then this is not a very interesting conjecture...

Comment: https://oeis.org/A050412

Comment: Do you agree with the proposed edit "Suppose we have the following recurrence $a_{n+1}=2a_n+1$ where $a_0$ is a fixed natural number. How do we show that there is an $n≥1$ s.t. $a_n$ is prime?" Is that what you meant?

Comment: According to the linked oeis, 509203 remains composite indefinitely throughout this process.  See also [The Riesel Problem](http://www.prothsearch.com/rieselprob.html)

Comment: @user1090793 Apart from that it is apparently refuted, why should this conjecture not be interesting ?

Comment: @Peter: My interpretation of OP's conjecture was as follows: "take a positive integer, multiply it by 2 and then add 1 as many times as you want; you'll always eventually hit a prime." In that case, this just reduces to the infinitude of primes. In that case I'd say the conjecture is not interesting since it's been known for quite some time. However, it seems OP was saying "iterate the process of doubling and adding 1," which is of course different

Comment: @user1090793 OK, that clarifies all.